# Bind functions to elements inserted in the DOM? (Implicitly?)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

This is probably jquery basics, but I can't find a solution after much googling.

How do you attach "non-events" to elements inserted in the DOM?
For events, like **click**, we can use `live()` or `bind()`.
How would you, for instance, initialize `tabs()` or `addClass()` to a new element?

Specifically, I'm trying to get tabs() to work in the content of an ajax loaded dialog, but I think the correct solution should be applicable to any situation.

I did see a trick that involved `$('body').mousemove()` which did work, but that is still binding to an event and obviously a hack.

For instance, how would you get addClass() to fire on a newly inserted table row?

I mean to do this implicitly, meaning that I don't want to write out specific instructions for every event that adds nodes to the dom, I just want it to "run in the background".

Let me know if this needs clarification, I see many similar questions on SO but no answers that have helped.

**EDIT:** Simple example: A page calls `$('a').addClass('highlight')` which works on all anchors in the page. A new anchor is then added to the page dynamically by jQuery, but does not get the class added.

**EDIT:** I have tried all kinds of bind(), trigger() and change() methods but I'm afraid I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to look at [livequery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery)  it will allow you to apply things to newly added elements

also if your adding the element you can do

```
$('body')append('<div>some content</div>').tabs();
```

or something like that

Comment: I did come across livequery but wasn't sure it was what I was after, I'm going to take a quick look at that, thank you.

Comment: @Madmartigan I modified my answer slightly

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after! Thank you so much, this script will be a core component for all my work from now on. Works perfectly.

Comment: For the record, the code that I'm using is 

`$('.tabs').livequery(function() {
  $(this).tabs();
 });`

Comment: That livequery function is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I know that I may contradicting your "non-event" rule here, but just by saying that you want something "triggered", you're already implying some kind of event.

In that case, may I suggest jQuery custom events? You may want to create a custom event, then trigger it manually somewhere in your code. It's not automatic (like when you add a row, BOOM, it fires™), but that's the closest thing I can think of with what you were describing.

Specifically, you may want to look at jQuery's `.bind()` and `.trigger()` methods.